# Extracting only certain portion of html in R

Tags: html, r, loops

I have two questions on how to extract certain portion of text from URLs
1. I want to extract text from these URLs, but want to remove financial statement tables (income statement, balance sheet, etc.) 
2. I want remove the portion after S-8 Risk Factors in the first URL, for example.

```
u <- "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/944508/000104746914007395/a2221329z424b7.htm"
ie <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application") 
ie$Navigate(u)
doc <- list()
doc[[u]] <- ie[["document"]][["body"]][["innerText"]] 
#ie$Quit()
doc=tolower(doc)
dic=c("breakthrough", "develop", "patent")
sent=unlist(strsplit(as.character(doc),split="\\."))[grep(paste(dic,collapse="|"),unlist(strsplit(as.character(doc),split="\\.")))]
write.csv(sent, "1.csv")
```

Comment: Have a look at `httr` and `xml2`. They will allow you to walk through the DOM of your website and not need you remote control internet explorer.

Comment: “`COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")`” … oh god. Please no. Use HTML scraping. And if you *really* need to interact with a browser, use (R)Selenium, not a COM controlled Internet Explorer.